# Finding vowels: re.compile pattern not keeping vowels of words together

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
import re

line = ("hello  moose pole  cccttt.ggg   cat   cow    car horse  dddfff arizona  mississippi   cleveland")

pattern = re.compile("[aAeEiIoOuU*]+", re.IGNORECASE)
while line:
    for word in pattern.findall(line):
        print(word+"\t"+"1")
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
```

Output coming out is:
[image: Output]

Want to achieve:

```
eo   1    
ooe  1    
oe   1    
     1    
a    1    
o    1    
a    1    
oe   1    
     1    
aioa  1    
iiii  1    
eea   1
```

Note: it is suppose to log a blank for words with no vowels. At the very least I would like to get the vowels gathered. Then I can fix the non-vowel word issues.

Comment: Why need regex for this?

Comment: You never told Python that you want words. You should break the text into words (whatever they are) and then apply your procedure to each word. And remove the `*` from the regex, it has no business there. And either remove 'AIUEO' from the regex or remove the flag `re.IGNORECASE` (you do not need both).

Comment: Yes. My issue was I was struggling with learning how to use this approach. I am a newbie to Python. I didn't have to use regex but I thought I needed to figure out how to use it should I ever. Appreciate everyone's help. I recognize most of you as I have found many of your posts helpful in the past. Thanks for taking the time to try to help those of us who are new to this.

Answer (score 0):

you can construct list first.

```
ln=line.split()
for i in ln:
         n=''
         for x in i:
             if x in 'aeiou':
                 n+=x
         print ( n + "\t" + "1" )
```

Comment: Also works perfectly. Thank you for taking the time. I have never posted here as it is a bit intimidating. I didn't want to post until I was sure I wasn't finding it already answered. I do use this site a lot for help and it has been great. Appreciate everyone on here. Now I will have to pay it forward and help someone. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you are looking for:

First create a splitting value, colon

```
a = re.sub('[^aeiou:]', '', re.sub(' +', ':', line), flags = re.I).split(':')

 for word in a: print(word+"\t"+"1")

eo      1
ooe     1
oe      1
        1
a       1
o       1
a       1
oe      1
        1
aioa    1
iiii    1
eea     1
```

Comment: That was perfect. It will fit in to the larger code I am using with. Is there a good place to read up on the uses of re and sub besides the confusing python documentation. I am still learning and I was trying to better understand how this all worked. I was going to see if there was any tutorials in Datacamp that might give me more grounding.

Comment: And thank you. I knew it had something to do with the pattern line and another try I did got me close but not there either.

Comment: @Anon. `re` is a module for regular expression. There are tons of websites that deal with this. Do not limit yourself to python since regular expression is a language on its own, and the moment you understand its building blocks, then you can use it in any language, including python.  start with the basics in Wikipedia and then read through the various sites. You can use [https://regex101.com/](https://regex101.com/) to practice or even python itself